# How to sort across rows in f#?

Tags: f#, sorting

I would like to sort some tab separated data that is of the following form.

```
Marketing, Advertising, PR  Graduate, Trainees  Oil, Gas, Alternative Energy    
Marketing, Advertising, PR  Graduate, Trainees  Public Sector & Services    
Marketing, Advertising, PR  Graduate, Trainees  Recruitment Sales   
Marketing, Advertising, PR  Graduate, Trainees  Secretarial, PAs, Administration    
Marketing, Advertising, PR  Graduate, Trainees  Senior Appointments 
Marketing, Advertising, PR  Graduate, Trainees  Telecommunications  
Marketing, Advertising, PR  Graduate, Trainees  Transport, Logistics    
Other   Graduate, Trainees  Banking, Insurance, Finance 
Other   Graduate, Trainees  Customer Services   
Other   Graduate, Trainees  Education   
Other   Graduate, Trainees  Health, Nursing 
Other   Graduate, Trainees  Legal   
Other   Graduate, Trainees  Management Consultancy
```

There is a mixture of single phrases words and multi word phrases. The words of the phrases have commas between them. The phrases are tab delimited.

I need to compare it with another set of data where the text cells have been helpfully sorted alphabetically.

Obviously this makes direct comparison difficult (impossible).

Following ovastus's suggestion below I have the following code

```
open System;;
open System.IO;;
#load @"BigDataModule.fs";;
open BigDataModule;;

let sample = "TruncatedData.txt";;

let outputFile = "SortedOutput.csv";;


let sortWithinRow (row:string) =
    let columns = row.Split([|'\t'|])
    let sortedColumns = 
        Seq.append
            (columns |> Seq.take (columns.Length) |> Seq.sort)
            [ columns.[columns.Length - 1] ]            
    sortedColumns |> String.concat ",";;

sample |> readLines |>  Seq.map sortWithinRow |> saveTo (outputFile);;
```

Where readLines and saveTo are functions in my own Big Data module for reading in files and saving outputs.

When I get the output from this script, unfortunately the sort has not produced the desired result and the rows are still not sorted alphabetically.

If anyone can help me to further refine my script I will be very grateful.

I apologise for wasting time, having originally underdetermined the problem by oversimplifying the format of the input.

EDIT 1: Clarified I have saved the data as a csv file and will do this in F#.

EDIT 2: I have gotten rid of all of the extraneous parts of the data set, I just need to sort within these rows. I have also given further details of some code I have tried.

EDIT 3:

This was the original data frame I entered, which was an oversimplification

```
Alpha   Bravo   Tango   Delta   15.00
Bravo   Delta   Tango       20.30
Delta   Alpha   Tango   6.17   
Charlie Tango   Foxtrot Alpha   19.13
```

Comment: Are you trying to do this in Excel or F#, or in Excel controlled via automation from F#?

Comment: Sorry will edit. I'm trying to do it in F#, but the question has confused the two (I started off in Excel).

Comment: Would you consider keeping your older example? Otherwise the recent edit merely invalidates some good answers.

Comment: Ok, I'll add it back in when I get 5 minutes.

Comment: I'm considering deleting this question. I missed a lot of the structure of the data in my oversimplified example and it has confused the issue. I'm taking a different approach now, and need to ask a new question. I wonder if the more senior community members have a view on deletion.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if I understand correctly what you want, but if you want to generate this output:

```
 Alpha Bravo Delta Tango 15.00
 Bravo Delta Tango 20.30
 Alpha Delta Tango 6.17
 Alpha Charlie Foxtrot Tango 19.13
```

You can do it like this:

```
open System

let sample = """Alpha  Bravo Tango Delta    15.00
Bravo  Delta Tango          20.30
Delta  Alpha Tango          6.17
Charlie Tango Foxtrot Alpha 19.13""".Split [|'\n'|]

let sortWithinRow (row:string) =
    let columns = row.Split([|' '|], StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
    let sortedColumns = 
        Seq.append
            (columns |> Seq.take (columns.Length - 1) |> Seq.sort)
            [ columns.[columns.Length - 1] ]            
    sortedColumns |> String.concat " "

sample |> Seq.map sortWithinRow |> String.concat "\n"
```

Comment: Ok, yes that looks correct. I will give it a go and report back.

Comment: Hmm, something is wrong, it is sorting the whole file alphabetically. I'm going to play with it a bit more. The actual data structure is a little more complex than the way I've set it out here, so I suspect I've underdefined the problem which has caused the issue.

Answer (score 1):

What about the following?

```
sample |> 
  Seq.map (fun x -> x.Split('\t')) |> 
  Seq.map (Seq.map (fun x -> x.Trim())) |> 
  Seq.map (Seq.filter (fun x -> not (String.IsNullOrEmpty(x)))) |>
  Seq.map Seq.sort |> 
  Seq.map (String.concat '\t') |> 
  String.concat '\n';;
```

I can't type \t in a way that will paste for an example, so for an executable example I had to switch field delimiters to spaces

```
open System

let sample2 = """Alpha  Bravo Tango Delta    15.00
Bravo  Delta Tango          20.30
Delta  Alpha Tango          6.17
Charlie Tango Foxtrot Alpha 19.13""".Split [|'\n'|]

sample2 |> 
  Seq.map (fun x -> x.Split([|"  "|], StringSplitOptions.None)) |> 
  Seq.map (Seq.map (fun x -> x.Trim())) |> 
  Seq.map (Seq.filter (fun x -> not (String.IsNullOrEmpty(x)))) |>
  Seq.map Seq.sort |> 
  Seq.map (String.concat '\t') |> 
  String.concat '\n';;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using [F# Data](http://fsharp.github.com/FSharp.Data/)

```
[<Literal>]
let sample = """Text1,Text2,Text3,Text4,ValueField
Alpha,Bravo,Tango,Delta,15.00
Bravo,Delta,Tango,,20.30
Delta,Alpha,Tango,,6.17
Charlie,Tango,Foxtrot,Alpha,19.13"""

open FSharp.Data

let csv = CsvProvider<sample, Separator = ",">.Load("input.csv")

let sortedData = 
    csv.Data 
    |> Seq.sortBy (fun row -> row.Text1)
    |> Seq.map (fun row -> row.Columns |> String.concat ",")

System.IO.File.WriteAllLines("output.csv", sortedData)
```

If you want to sort by multiple fields you can just tuple them in the sorting function:

```
|> Seq.sortBy (fun row -> row.Text1, row.Text3)
```

Comment: I think he's looking to sort within each row, not across the rows.

Comment: This looks like it will sort the rows by the first text entry, rather than sorting the text entries within the rows. Or am i reading this incorrectly?